# How to get Azure Cosmo DB signature by Delphi

Tags: azure, delphi, azure-cosmosdb

My project needs to connect the Azure Cosmo DB by REST API. The Azure Cosmo DB connection requires to pass a HMACSHA256 signature to the HTTP header. I tried to use THashSHA2.GetHMAC(Data, Key) function in Delphi 10.2 to get this signature. In order to verify the result, I run the sample code in C# (downloaded from MS) to verify the result generated by Delphi. Unfortunately, they are not the same!
C# : 2LuKbSl8RkLc0eKhjQv4oCpXzRcmR02L9sDfSxSB5HA=
Delphi: 2ca409c9a26aa3ed6c772b6bda5bbe66bcd0d929c3ca4359f19ea42314437e5a
I verify the Delphi result by the online HMACSHA256 generator. Delphi is correct.

I searched over the web to find another way to generate the signature. I got TIdHMACSHA256 (using IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary). I tried the code but also no luck. The result (96OyCOmXzODAP9CljJgleuG5J5c4nIDeiSlr3hdcpYY=) is also not the same as the one generated by C#.

I noticed that C# code run Convert.FromBase64String(key) to convert the key to byte, generate the hash and then Convert.ToBase64String(hashPayLoad) to signature. I suspect the wrong result in Delphi is missing this kind of steps. But I do not know how to do it.

Do anyone have experience generating Azure Cosmo DB signature by Delphi? Please help!

Comment: You have misspelled "Cosmos", neglected to mention whether *any* of those results actually work, and not shown what you're actually including to generate the hash

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2003194/8041231)?

Comment: Sorry for my typo. I'm new to stackoverflow. I can't find any edit link to update my question. I've used two procedures that I find on the web to hash the signature.

Comment: The first one   
function GenerateSignature(const AData, AKey: string): string;
var
  AHMAC: TIdBytes;
  bytes: TBytes;

begin
  IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary;
  if not TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then
    ...;
  with TIdHMACSHA256.Create do

    Key := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(AKey);

    AHMAC := HashValue(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(AData));
.....
  result := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(AHMAC);

end;
The second one 
result:= THashSHA2.GetHMAC(ACode, AKey);

None of them produce the same result as C#

Comment: I'm sorry that I do not know how to add a line feed to my above code.

Answer (score 0):

After searching all possible websites and a lot of trial and error, I get the solution finally. The result is same as the signature generated from C#. The code was modified from "https://www.delphipraxis.net/190563-dxe7-indy-hmac-sha256-encoding.html"

function GenerateCosmosDBSignature(const AData, AKey: string): string;
var
  AHMAC: TIdBytes;
  bytes: TBytes;

begin

IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary;

if not TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then

```
raise Exception.Create('SHA-256 hashing is not available!');
```

with TIdHMACSHA256.Create do

try

```
//original
//Key := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(AKey);
//AHMAC := HashValue(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(AData));

//after modified
Key := TIdBytes(TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(AKey));
AHMAC := HashValue(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(AData));
```

finally

```
Free;
```

end;

//original

//result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(AHMAC);

//after modified

result:= AnsiString(TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(System.TArray(AHMAC)));

end;

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the Cosmos DB signature by using Delphi System.Hash

function GenerateCosmosDBSignature(const AData, AKey: string): string;
var
  keyBytes, dataBytes: TBytes;

begin

keyBytes:=TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(AKey);
  dataBytes:=TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AData);

result:= AnsiString(TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes(dataBytes, keyBytes)));

end;